# Making shabbat morning kiddush at shul and again at home... what is the story?

Tags: halacha

Say everyone heard kiddush at shul on shabbat morning. Now all are at home. Do we make kiddush again?

And if so, is that from a source, or just because it feels like the right thing to do?

Ditto related to hamotzi.

Comment: Possibly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5877/making-kiddush-havdalah-twice

Comment: https://torah.org/torah-portion/weekly-halacha-5771-vaera/

Comment: There is the idea of kiddush b'makom seudah. You need to hear kiddush in the place where you make hamotzi and eat bread.

Answer (score 2):

Kiddush needs to be said before your morning meal (OC 289:1) but need not, though can be, said before later meals (291:4).

[Most rishonim](https://books.google.com/books?id=2EqoDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT26&lpg=PT26&dq=%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C+%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%95%D7%91+%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9+%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%9D+%D7%A1%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94&source=bl&ots=e5XR7tAKcf&sig=ACfU3U0oBsXag3fZrsPtJ2MLPAJCc5eEqw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjD7r2Ao5n5AhXUkIkEHSbLAnIQ6AF6BAgPEAM#v=onepage&q=%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C%20%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%95%D7%91%20%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%20%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%9D%20%D7%A1%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94&f=false) held that a meal is constituted by bread (or at least [pseudo-bread](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/80701/759) intended as a fixed meal) and most rishonim held that, like the evening kiddush, you may not eat before the morning kiddush.

Accordingly, if you ate something subject to "hamotzi" at shul after kiddush, then you needn't say kiddush again. If you didn't eat at shul, you must say kiddush before your meal at home. If you ate other foods relying on the minority positions above (not unreasonable, since this is a matter of rabbinic law and since some say you can eat before real kiddush anyway) then it probably makes sense to say kiddush before your main bread meal as well to be strict for the majority position.

Answer (score 0):

This boils down to a concept called "Kiddush b'makom seuda" - "Kiddush in the place of one's meal.

Halachapedia gives a good summary [here](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Kiddush):

> In the place where one made Kiddish one should make sure to have a meal there. This principle is called by chazal Kiddush Bimakom Seuda.<sup>[74]</sup> This applies both for the nighttime and daytime Kiddush.<sup>[75]</sup>

---

> <sup>[74]</sup> Shmuel in [Gemara Pesachim 101a](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.101a.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says that one should only say Kiddush in the place where one is going to have a meal. The Rosh ([Pesachim 10:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Rosh_on_Pesachim.10.5.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)) says that this is based on the pasuk "VeKarata LeShabbat Oneg" ([Yishayahu 58:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.58.13?lang=bi)) which Chazal explain with "Kriyah" as a reference to Kiddush and "Oneg" to the meal and so the pasuk means, in the place of Oneg one should have Kriyah. [Shulchan Aruch O.C. 273:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.273.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 77:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.77.14?lang=bi) codify this as the halacha.
>
> <sup>[75]</sup> Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 77:14

Comment: While certainly a relevant concept, this doesn't seem to address the question directly.